# Cakephp3.0 Authentication issue

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

Problem I am facing I can authenticate using blog tutorial but when I am doing the same thing with patients table and I want to login through url/patients/login but everytime I authenticate it said incorrect username and password and in adding user how can I add hash password .

Or anyone can suggest me code where in users login access I can redirect user based on role like admin and author how can I check if user is admin redirect to admin dashboard and if it is author is it possible if yes then please give login function code

Comment: You should reed the cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html and than ask a clearer question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching on net how to add a multi level user authentication system I find a solution I am using blog example as full code and in login system I added this code :

```
 public function login()
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    if ($user['role'] === 'admin') {
        $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'articles']);
    } 
    else if ($user['role'] === 'author'){
         $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login' ,'controller' => 'users']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
}
```

This is a very simple solution  I have just added few lines of code